# ZMQ. Как отправить и принять большое количество слов

Tags: c++, сокет, клиент-сервер, zeromq

Нужно передать текстовый файл с сервера клиенту.

Сделать это нужно через **zmq**.

Пытался использовать *zmq_msg_send*, но почему-то сообщение до клиента не доходит

Вот мой кривокод отправки-получения сообщений:

Клиент:

```
// Прием сообщений
struct  MyMessen * Recv1(void *arg) {
    struct MyMessen *mes = (struct MyMessen *) arg;
    int errcode;
    char exitkey = 0;

    // Отправка
    zmq_msg_t packet;

    // Прием
    zmq_msg_init(&packet);
    while (exitkey < 10) {
        errcode = zmq_msg_recv(&packet, mes->requester, ZMQ_DONTWAIT);
        if (errcode == -1) {
            exitkey++;
            // Время на обработку запроса
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(300));
        }
        else exitkey = 10;
    }
    mes = (struct MyMessen *)zmq_msg_data(&packet);
    if (errcode == -1) mes->Answer2 = 100;
    zmq_msg_close(&packet);

    // Значение ответа
    return mes;
}
```

Сервер:

```
// Отправка сообщений
void SendPac(void *arg, void * responsSocket, bool strict) {
    struct MyMessen *mes = (struct MyMessen *) arg;
    zmq_msg_t packet;
    zmq_msg_init_size(&packet, sizeof(struct MyMessen));
    memcpy(zmq_msg_data(&packet), mes, sizeof(struct MyMessen));
    if (!strict)
        zmq_msg_send(&packet, responsSocket, ZMQ_DONTWAIT); else
        zmq_msg_send(&packet, responsSocket, 0);
    zmq_msg_close(&packet);
}
```

Также код, составляющий и распознающий сообщения:

Сервер:

```
// Отправка Tells
void SendTells(char login[257], void *arg, void * responsSocket) {
    struct MyMessen *mes = (struct MyMessen *) arg;
    char TellsAdress[1024];
    int WordCount = 0;
    int i;

    FILE * TellsFile;

    sprintf_s(TellsAdress, "%s%c%s%s", DBMesAdress, '/', login, "/tells.cat");
    if (fopen_s(&TellsFile, TellsAdress, "r+") != 0) {
        printf_s(" FileSystem ERROR!\n");
        mes->Answer2 = -2;
        SendPac(mes, responsSocket, false);
        return;
    }

    while (fscanf_s(TellsFile, "%s", TellsAdress, 1024) >= 1) WordCount++;
    mes->Answer2 = WordCount;
    SendPac(mes, responsSocket, false);


    fseek(TellsFile, 0, SEEK_SET);

    for (i = 0; i < WordCount; i++) {
        fscanf_s(TellsFile, "%s", mes->Answer1, 1024);
        mes->Answer2 = i;
        SendPac(mes, responsSocket, false); // Эти сообщения НЕ доходят
    }
    fclose(TellsFile);
}
```

Клиент:

```
// Получение tells
bool SFr_ZMQ_GetTells(char SessionID[257], FILE *UserTellsFile) {

    // Переменные
    void             * context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void             * sendss = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_REQ);

    char             ServerAdr[1024];
    int              errcode = 0;

    char ** TextFile;

    int WordCount = 0;
    int i, j;



    struct MyMessen mes;
    struct MyMessen * answer = NULL;


    // Составление адресса сервера
    for (errcode = 0; errcode < 1024; errcode++) ServerAdr[errcode] = 0;
    sprintf_s(ServerAdr, "%s%s%c%s", ServerProt, ServerIP, ':', ServerPort);

    // Попытка подключения к серверу 
    errcode = zmq_connect(sendss, ServerAdr);
    if (errcode != 0) return false;

    // Составление письма
    for (errcode = 0; errcode < 257; errcode++) mes.login[errcode] = mes.pass[errcode] = 0;
    mes.requester = sendss;
    sprintf_s(mes.SessionID, "%s", SessionID);
    mes.operation = 15;

    // Отправка письма
    answer = SendRecv1(&mes);
    WordCount = answer->Answer2;
    if (WordCount < 0) return false;

    // Выделение памяти 
    TextFile = (char**)malloc(WordCount * sizeof(char*));

    // Получение писем с текстом (НЕ РАБОТАЕТ)
    for (i = 0; i < WordCount; i++) {
        answer = Recv1(&mes);
        TextFile[i] = (char*)malloc(257 * sizeof(char));
        for (j = 0; j < 257; j++) TextFile[i][j] = (answer->Answer1)[j];
        if (answer->Answer2 != i) {
            for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) free(TextFile[j]);
            free(TextFile);
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Уничтожение левых сообщений
    while (answer->Answer2 != 100) answer = Recv1(&mes);

    // Сохраняем текст в файл
    for (i = 1; i < WordCount; i=i+2) fprintf(UserTellsFile, "%s%s%c", TextFile[i - 1], TextFile[i], '\n');

    // Освобождение памяти
    for (j = 0; j <= WordCount; j++) free(TextFile[j]);
    free(TextFile);
    zmq_close(sendss);

    // Выход
    return answer;
}
```

Структура сообщения:

```
#ifndef MESSEN_H
#define MESSEN_H

struct MyMessen {
    char login[257];
    char pass[257];
    char SessionID[257];

    unsigned char operation;

    void * requester;

    char Answer1[257];
    int  Answer2;
};

#endif
```

Прошу помочь: или написать скрипт отправки большого объема текста или исправить мой текст (в комментариях обозначил, где не работает)

Ссылка на весь проект: https://yadi.sk/d/Zxr2Mf6ki3S0jQ